# How to delete a specific object out of an array

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say we have this array :

```
Student[] students = new Student[3];
students[0] = new Student() { Number = 123, Name = "Jansen", Firstname = "Tom" };
students[1] = new Student() { Number = 456, Name = "Tomsen", Firstname = "Jan" };
students[2] = new Student() { Number = 789, Name = "Jackson", Firstname = "Ryan" };
```

I want to remove the student object with Number 456 so I call my method :

```
RemoveStudentWithNumber(456);
```

This is what I tried :

```
public void RemoveStudentWithNumber(int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
    {
        if (students[i].Number == number) 
        {
            students[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This does delete the correct student but it replaces it with an empty line in the array.
So I actually want to reduce the lenght of the array when the method is called correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array's in C# cannot easily have their size changed - you need to create a new array.

In this situation, you're better-off using a generic `List`.

```
var students = new List<Student>();
students.Add(new Student() { Number = 123, Name = "Jansen", Firstname = "Tom" });
students.Add(new Student() { Number = 456, Name = "Tomsen", Firstname = "Jan" });
students.Add(new Student() { Number = 789, Name = "Jackson", Firstname = "Ryan" });
```

and then

```
students.RemoveAt(/*index to remove*/);
```

Alternatively, you could use Linq, and create a new array:

```
students = students.Where(s = s.Number != number).ToArray();
```

Comment: there isn't a solution without List ? In the exercise they say I should use arrays.

Comment: Of course you can move all subsequent elements of the array one down (which would leave the empty line at the end where it may go unnoticed), or you can create a new array which has one element less and copy everything over. No need for a list, if that's a hard requirement

Comment: While it may not be possible to change the size of an array proper, one can come pretty close using the, well, `Resize` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the array into an arraylist then remove an item like this:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList tempList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
tempList.AddRange(students);
tempList.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
students = tempList.ToArray(typeof(Student)) as Student[];
```

You are better of not using a normal array in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot live with an empty line even at the end, cf. my comment to Dave's solution, you *can* subsequently resize the array so that it contains one element less. Cf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

The function could look like this (untested):

```
public void RemoveStudentWithNumber(int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
    {
        if (students[i].Number == number)
        {
            // move all subsequent students one down,
            // closing the gap.
            if( i != students.Length-1) 
            {
                Array.Copy(students, i+1, students, i, students.Length-i-1);
            }
            // Now resize. 
            Array.Resize(ref students, students.Length-1);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd also check whether it is guaranteed that the abort condition of the outer for loop is evaluated for each cycle because students.Length possibly changes in the loop. (I'd think it's ok.)